# How to use ref.current from context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Hi i have ref in context.

```js
// MyContextProvider
divRef = React.createContext<HTMLDivElement>();

componentDidMount() {
  this.divRef.current; // Ok
}

render() {
  return <MyContext.Provider value={{ divRef: this.divRef }} >{this.props.children}</MyContext.Provider>;
}
```

In the child component:

```js
// MyComponent
componentDidMount() {
  this.context.divRef.current // Error Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLDivElement| null) => void'
}

render () {
  return <div ref={this.context.divRef}>example</div>;
}
```

when i trying to use `divRef.current` i getting Error:

```
any
Property 'current' does not exist on type 'RefObject | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)'.
Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void'.
```

But in the the Wrapper over the context (`MyContextProvider`) I can use and read the `ref.current`.

Also i've tried that:

```js
if (this.context.divRef) {
  this.context.divRef.current // Same Error
}
```

Why ? How can i use divRef.current ?

P.S. Maybe i need to create 1 more ref in the child component, and already work with it, and assign it to the ref obtained from the context, but i don't know how to do it (i've tried use ref callback, but got a lot of errors):

something like this:

```js
localRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

render() {
  return (<div ref={(div) => {
    this.localRef = div;
    this.context.divRef = div;
  }}>
    example
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've incorrectly typed Context. Your code snippets are insufficient. Your context has type `RefObject | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)` and should have `RefObject`.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak, but that is all I have. i define context: `divRef = React.createContext<HTMLDivElement>();` and pass it to Context.Provider as value, after i getting divRef from context and pass to component as ref

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak, omg i'm inattentive, you are right, i've incorrectly typed Context.
i used `React.Ref<HTMLDivElement> instead of React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>.

thanks a lot